# how to validate text area with out any phonenumber,name,emailid,urls

Tags: javascript, jquery

how to validate the text area field with out these values  phone number, email address or any url in your messages .

if any of the details given automatically reject messages with contact information?? suggest me

```
<form action="main.php" method="post">
<textarea data-questionable="true" id="message_body" name="message_text" rows="7" class="submit-text-box"></textarea>
<br/>
<input type='submit' name='send' Value='Send Details' onclick='validate()' />
</form>
```

Comment: This isn't quite how to ask questions here but I'll throw you a bone and say you can start with RegEx or a string search with `indexOf`

Comment: PS - go http://stackoverflow.com/tour <-there to find out what NOT to do when asking a question (about two sections down)

Answer (score 0):

Your question is kind of unclear but it sounds like you want to make sure there are no phone numbers, email addresses or urls in a text area. Below is some code to validate that each piece is NOT existent in the text area. The following code will alert if any of those three fields are present in the text area.

Phone Number:

```
    function phonenumber(inputtxt)  
    {  
      var phoneno = /^\d{10}$/;  
      if((inputtxt.value.match(phoneno))  
            {  
          alert("message");
          return false;  
            }  
          else  
            {    
            return true;  
            }  
    }
```

Email:

```
var emailPat = /^(\".*\"|[A-Za-z]\w*)@(\[\d{1,3}(\.\d{1,3}){3}]|[A-Za-z]\w*(\.[A-Za-z]\w*)+)$/
var EmailmatchArray = Email.match(emailPat);
if (EmailmatchArray != null) {
    alert("Text contains an email!");
    return false;
}else{
   return true;
   }
```

URL:

```
   var Url = "^[A-Za-z]+://[A-Za-z0-9-_]+\\.[A-Za-z0-9-_%&\?\/.=]+$";
   var isURL = WebUrl.match(Url);
   if (isURL != null) {
   alert("Contains a URL.");
   return false;
}else{
   return true;
   }
```

Comment: i want to validate textarea,so that user canot enter words like phone number, email address or any url .how i can stop the user from entering these words using javascript.